# Insert 'Load Records from File' on Document Templates screen

Tags: acumatica

I want to import data using excel file into Document Template.
So, I trying to setup 'Load Records from File' button on screen SM209020 (Document Templates)

However, the 'Load Records from File' button is disabled. I click upload for Excel but nothing happen ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVpUh.png)

ScreenId=SM209020 > tab Tasks ( Allow upload = true)

Here is my code

```
`using System;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.SM
{
  public class AUTemplateController_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.SM.AUTemplateController>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    [PXImport(typeof(AUTemplateData))]
    public PXSelect<AUTemplateData, AUTemplate, 
    Where<AUTemplate.templateID,Equal<Current<AUTemplateData.templateId>>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<AUTemplate.templateID, Asc<AUTemplateData.active, Asc<AUTemplateData.line,  
    Asc<AUTemplateData.container,Asc<AUTemplateData.view, Asc<AUTemplateData.rowType,  
    Asc<AUTemplateData.field, Asc<AUTemplateData.view >>>>>>>>> Items;
    #endregion
  }
}`
```

My code it is not working. How can i fix it ?
Can someone please help me.

I hope to be able to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Once I edited your PXSelect in your example and set Grid / Mode / AllowUpload to True in the screen editor, the upload button was enabled on 23R1.

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.SM
{
    public class AUTemplateController_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AUTemplateController>
    {
        #region Views
        [PXImport(typeof(AUTemplateData))]
        public PXSelect<AUTemplateData,
        Where<Current<AUTemplate.templateID>,Equal<Current<AUTemplateData.templateId>>>,
        OrderBy<Asc<AUTemplate.templateID, Asc<AUTemplateData.active, Asc<AUTemplateData.line,  
            Asc<AUTemplateData.container,Asc<AUTemplateData.view, Asc<AUTemplateData.rowType,  
                Asc<AUTemplateData.field, Asc<AUTemplateData.view >>>>>>>>>> Items;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it fix your import button problem?

Comment: I tried your method it works however there are some problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227967/load-records-from-file-on-document-templates-screen-is-missing-properties