# 'Load Records from File' on Document Templates screen is missing properties

Tags: acumatica

I have created 'Load Records from File' on Document Templates screen.

[Load Records from File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAWFE.png)

However, when I Import, the 'TemplateId' attribute is missing in Property Name

['TemplateId' attribute is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHXPe.png)

In the AUTemplateData table, there is the attribute 'TemplateId'

[table AUTemplateData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdWfE.png)

Here is my code

```
`using System;
 using PX.Objects;
 using PX.Data;

 namespace PX.SM
 {
  public class AUTemplateController_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.SM.AUTemplateController>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    [PXImport(typeof(AUTemplateData))]
    public PXSelect<AUTemplateData, 
  
    Where<AUTemplateData.templateId,Equal<Current<AUTemplate.templateID>>>,
  
    OrderBy< Asc<AUTemplateData.active, Asc<AUTemplateData.line, Asc<AUTemplateData.container,
    Asc<AUTemplateData.view, Asc<AUTemplateData.rowType, Asc<AUTemplateData.field,     
    Asc<AUTemplateData.value>>>>>>>>>Items;
     #endregion
  }
 }`
```

My code is wrong. How can i fix it ? Can someone please help me.

I hope to be able to fix my problem

Comment: What is the screen I'd for the Document Template screen you reference?